# Using PHP to remove a selected item from drop down, amongst others

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, sql-update

Hiya:
I'm trying to use PHP to remove selected item in a drop down menu, but all to know avail. Also, when I click on the same submit button that I'll use to remove selected list, I want to UPDATE the MySQL database. I tried using JavaScript, but couldn't use both languages on that submit input button.

This is my code for creating the drop down menu and button

```
$opts        = array("guns", "knives", "ammo");
$selected    = array($_POST['selectMenu']);
$revisedOpts = array_diff($opts, $selected);
```

HTML

```
<select name='selectMenu'>
<?php
foreach($revisedOpts as $v) {
     echo "<option>".$v."</option>";
}
?>
</select><input name="Collect" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

This is the mysql_query

```
if (isset($_POST['Collect'])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE Player SET score = score+10
                 WHERE name = 'Rob Jackson' AND rank = 'Lieutenant'");
}
```

Comment: Please post a bit more PHP code you have. Also, have you tried writing a MySQL query to do what you want? If so, can you post it please? This question is a little too ambiguous in some places. In other news, welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Echo `$_POST['selectMenu']` to make sure it gives you the name of an object and not that objects id or array index.

Comment: Where exactly? Inside the select tag...pls

Comment: What's this trend of making first person shooter with PHP?