# Clearing a selected item from a dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I used the code below to remove a selected item from drop down, but when I remove one, the other item pops up. For example, if these are my options: "guns, cars, money", as I select and delete guns, cars and money remains. However, if I select cars and delete it, the deleted guns options pops up again. It is frustrating.

```
<?php
    $opts = array("guns","knives","ammo");
    $selected = array($_POST['selectMenu']);
    $revisedOpts = array_diff($opts,$selected);
?>

<form  method="post">
<select name='selectMenu'><?php
    foreach($revisedOpts as $v) {
        echo "<option>".$v."</option>";
    }
?></select>
<input onclick="array_diff()" name="Collect" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Kelvin, you can mark multiple lines of code an then click the "Code Sample" button, then your code will be formated even more beautiful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP to remove a selected item from drop down, amongst others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192575/using-php-to-remove-a-selected-item-from-drop-down-amongst-others)

Comment: powtac dont think that is the correct dup, see link below ;)

Comment: No, its not a duplicate. I needed an answer for that one concerning a dual function on one button, and I got it. However, I found out that the code above doesn#t work

Comment: You're confusing PHP and Javascript. PHP runs on the server and generates your webpage. The user's browser receives that generated HTML/JS and runs it. PHP has no further involvement or existence after transmission.

Answer (score 1):

PHP only acts when the page is loaded, and you load the same code over and over. In order for previously deleted options to stay deleted, you need some kind of data persistence (like a database).  Otherwise, you can use javascript to manipulate the select options on the client side browser. [Here is a good discussion](http://dev-notes.com/code.php?q=59)

If you must bind the action to `onclick()` and receive the event on the server side, then you will need to use an AJAX call.  The `onclick` calls a separate PHP script which deletes the option and returns some kind of success message.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use JS because I'm using the same submit button to carry out a mysql_query....here's the link to the work. When you collect an item, it should be deleted, and add 10 points to your score.. Click here: http://www.thirdworld.vacau.com/dropdown.php

Comment: once again, you do not use buttons to run sql queries. also js is able to interrupt clicks and do things, then either allow or stop the default action of submitting a form. you need to learn about javascript a bit.

Comment: If a submit button's `onclick` returns `false`, the submit will not take place.  This is what @dogmatic69 is referring to.  You really need to read up on AJAX before you will be able to complete what you're trying to do. See Mozilla's documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax

Comment: Using jQuery's AJAX functions is probably the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

you want to have a look at some js code to do this. look at something like that http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial_mixed2b.html

Comment: Sorry, but that's totally out of what I want to do. You see, I cant use JS on this button because it's going to carry out a mysql_query as well. What I need is a php code to remove selected item from a dropdown menu.

Comment: so why onclick="array_diff()" seems like you need to figure out the difference between client side and server side

Comment: @Kelvin: Sorry, but the fact that you are asking this question demonstrates that you have made a fundamental misunderstanding. I suggest listening to the answers you get.

Comment: @Tomalak: This won't help me know the errors would it. Please, only comment if you want to help. "Fundamental Misunderstanding" doesn't seem like any help.. No offence :)

Comment: @Kelvin: Don't be rude. dogmatic69 suggested a great solution and you threw it out pretending that you know better: you don't! You do indeed have a fundamental misunderstanding of server- and client- side web technologies, and I am trying to help you to realise that so that you will be open to trying out some of the great solutions provided to you here. Hopefully, in the process of doing so, you will gain understanding and will have been helped.

Comment: @Tomalak: I didn't throw out any suggestions. Im doing so many things at the same time, and didn't see it. Do not conclude, when you aren't sure. I understand what y'all saying, that's why I have created any question. Pls, do check it out.

Comment: @Kelvin: I am sure. Unfortunately you don't seem to be listening to me. :( Good luck.

Comment: @Tomalak, I am listening to you, if not I wont be replying every single time. Now, pls do check this question, and see if you can help me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193646/combing-js-and-php-on-one-button-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

use jquery
[jquery auto suggestion](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)