# Combing JS and PHP on one button. Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript

Hiya:
i know some people would be so tired of my questions, but I'm working on a uni project and need to get it done as soon as possible. This question is about using JS on a button(button) and sending a php_my_sql update on the same button. The problem is JS uses button, right? but PHP uses button(submit). How can I get these two to work on one of these buttons, cuz there has to be only one button.

this is my code for JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formAction(){
    var x=document.getElementById("collect")
    x.remove(x.selectedIndex)
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <select id="collect" name="Select1" style="width: 193px">
    <option>guns</option>
    <option>knife</option>
    </select> <input type="**submit/button**" onclick="formAction()" name="Collect"  value="Collect" /></form>
```

PHP

```
    <? 
    if (isset($_POST['Collect'])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE Player SET score = score+10
    WHERE name = 'Rob Jackson' AND rank = 'Lieutenant'");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Is your button getting displayed? Not so sure about the markup here `<input type="**submit/button**"`, maybe you meant `<input type="submit"`. I can edit this for you, if this is just a typo error.

Comment: @erickb: That is not typo he is not sure which one to use in this situation

Comment: your [all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193312/clearing-a-selected-item-from-a-dropdown-using-php) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192575/using-php-to-remove-a-selected-item-from-drop-down-amongst-others)  are same

Comment: PHP has no buttons. PHP is a server-side scripting language. The user's browser -- which renders HTML and runs JS -- has no knowledge of PHP.

Comment: @Tomalak: Brilliant....That solves a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a way

Submit the form through JS after removing parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formAction(){
        var x=document.getElementById("collect")
        x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

    </script>
```

Input type button

```
<input type="button" onclick="formAction()" name="Collect"  value="Collect" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed jQuery and use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can interact with the button whilst the user is navigating the page and entering data into the form. The instant the user pushes the submit button and the request for the form submission is sent JS no longer has control. The request is sent to the form's action (most likely a PHP file) which processes the request and gives an answer back.
If you really need to combine the two, look into AJAX.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. i'm trying to check out AJAX, but I'm not so good at it

Comment: If you need any help, be sure to ask on SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formAction(){
    var x=document.getElementById("collect");
    x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
    submit_form();
}
function submit_form() {
    document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
<form method="post" name='form1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Collect'/>
    <select id="collect" name="Select1" style="width: 193px">
    <option>guns</option>
    <option>knife</option>
    </select> <input type="button" onclick="formAction()" name="Collect"  value="Collect" /></form>
<? 
    if (isset($_POST['Collect'])) {
    //do whatever update you want
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

Make this modification in the form tag

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return formAction()">
```

In JavaScript function add a line "return true;" at the end of the function.

Voila ..!!! you are done..!!

Enjoy..!!

Comment: Doesn't work :( It does the Javascript aspect, but doesn't update the mysql

Comment: long time ago I learned to always use `onsbumit="return(formAction());"` Although I forgot the reason for using the braces, it might still be relevant.